# Dynamically load content into Content Slider

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, slideshow, bxslider

I'm developing a site which utilises the bx slider to create a full screen presentation style slideshow website.

At the moment the slides are all hard coded into the homepage like so:

```
<ul class="bxslider group">


<li>
  <div class="container" id="section1">
   ..content
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <div class="container" id="section2">
   ..content
  </div>
</li>

 <!-- and so on -->

</ul>
```

I also have each slide's content in html files (without the 'li's) in files named page-2.html, page-3.html like so:

```
<div class="container" id="section2">
   ..content
  </div>
```

How can I code it so the slideshow pulls the data from the corresponding html page for each slide? Calculating how many pages there are and how many slides to produce if possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      mode: 'horizontal'
    });

    $('ul.bxslider li .container').each(function(k, v) {
        $(this).append('<div/>').load('page-' + (k+1) + '.html');
    }).promise().done(function() { slider.reloadSlider() });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<ul class="bxslider group">

<li>
  <div id="section1" class="container">
   ..content
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <div id="section2" class="container">
   ..content
  </div>
</li>

</ul>
```

This code will load your pages into the containers. It will use the the index of the container class (+1) for the page-{#}.html. Alternatively you could use the section id instead of `(k+1)` if you replaced it with something like `($(this).attr('id').split('section')[1])`

Comment: 1. Loop through `container` classes
2. Append a div
3. Load html page into div... I'll update post.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway for it to calculate how many pages there are and then create the slides, instead of hardcoding them and then appending?

Comment: You could just have the content in one page and use separate divs for each since you can specify a specific element of the page to [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) with jQuery.

Comment: Not currently, but I can do depending on the best solution. Also, i've just tried it out and it only seems to import the first slide.. the following slides fail?

Comment: I updated post for `$('ul.bxslider li .container')` instead of `$('.container')` in case you have container classes in the page you are loading

Comment: I think it's something to do with bxslider & having to reload it. Thanks for your help, in theory it works.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to like it, I appreciate your help though! I might just import each page manually through php, might be easier.